# Is this "Tayō-sei no naka no tōitsu" a correct translation of "Unity in Diversity"?

Tags: translation

Can someone let me know if this is the proper way to say the sentence "Unity in Diversity"?
I know that the literal translation would be "Diversity in Unity". Just wanted to know is correct wording and grammar for the sentence.

Thank you

Comment: the word "naka" represents "inside" rather than the word "in" which is used to mean something close to "through" or "by"... probably a better word choice in Japanese would be "de" or "ni", but I'm not sure which sounds more natural, or if there is a better, idiomatic way to express this idea...

Comment: According to the [Motto of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motto_of_the_European_Union) Wikipedia page, the official motto *In varietate concordia* (in Latin) is equivalent to "Unity in diversity" in English; and the Japanese Wikipedia page [欧州連合](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AC%A7%E5%B7%9E%E9%80%A3%E5%90%88) translates it as **多様性における統一** (Tayōsei ni okeru  tōitsu).

Comment: @ericさん ？「で」 or 「に」を使うのってちょっと無理じゃない？（「多様性**に**おける～」なら「に」使えるけど・・・） 「多様性の中の統一」って、いいと思いますけど・・・結構使われてるみたいだし。。。→ https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q="多様性の中の統一"+"Unity+in+Diversity"&oq